# SQL Server Management Studio 16.4.1 - Will not run

Tags: ssms-2016

Yesterday I updated SSMS from 16.3 to 16.4.1, rebooted and then installed the Window 10 Anniversary Update from Windows update. Everything on my PC seemed to be running fine.

However, trying to open SSMS today for the first time since the update and nothing happens. There is no error message and nothing is created in Event Viewer.

I have tried repairing the installation, which didn't fix the problem, and reinstalling the application which again did not fix the problem.

I can see in Process Monitor that the process exits with status 0 and it doesn't appear there is any effort made to write to a log file.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with this release?

**Edit:** The problem is resolved by uninstalling 16.4.1 and reinstalling 16.3, which makes me think something is broken in the latest release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the solution, after rolling back to 16.3, was to install the Community edition of Visual Studio 2015 and then install 16.4.1 again.